# How to create a button control which is grayed out/disabled for a certain interval of time?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I want to create a canvas which shows ads for like 10 sec and a button control which is grayed out for 10 seconds and after 10 seconds enables user to close the ad canvas.

I don't know how to create that button control. Somebody help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to go down the viewmodel route, you can use a Storyboard for this.

I threw together this MainPage:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
    x:Class="PhoneApp1.MainPage" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" d:DesignHeight="800" d:DesignWidth="480">
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="DelayEnableButton">
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.IsEnabled)" Storyboard.TargetName="button">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:10">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <System:Boolean>True</System:Boolean>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" Height="100" Margin="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsEnabled="False"/>
    </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

The important parts are that the button has a name, and this name is specified in the Storyboard definition. The Storyboard is set to change IsEnabled to True at 10 seconds. Then in the MainPage.xaml.cs I kick of the Storyboard in the Loaded event:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
    }

    void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DelayEnableButton.Begin();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting error at
InitializeComponent(); 

and

DelayEnableButton.Begin(); 


it is saying that this does not exists in the current context
I have copied your code in my xaml and cs file.
maybe some "using" statements are missing from the code behind..??

Comment: You need to fix the x:Class definition to match your namespace in MainPage.xaml

Answer (score 3):

Bind the IsEnabled of the button to a property in your Viewmodel such as IsAdDisplayed. Then set this property to true when the app starts up, and, using a timer, set it to false after 10 seconds.